# How to infer all of the possible generic types in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that accepts a record of `Handler<I, O>` and returns a function that returns the `O` of one of the handlers:

```js
type Handler<I, O> = { i: I, o: O, handler: (i: I) => O };

function handlerGroup<I, O>(handlers: Record<string, Handler<I, O>>): (key: string) => O {
  return (key: string) => {
    const { i, handler } = handlers[key];
    return handler(i);
  }
}
```

For example:

```js
const handleT1: Handler<number, number> = { i: 1, o: 1, handler: (i) => i }
const handleT2: Handler<number, string> = { i: 1, o: "1", handler: (i) => i.toString() }

handlerGroup({ T1: handleT1 }) //: (key: string) => number
handlerGroup({ T2: handleT2 }) //: (key: string) => string
```

But the problem starts when I try to add more than 1 record:

```js
// Type 'Handler<number, string>' is not assignable to type 'Handler<number, number>'.
//   Types of property 'o' are incompatible.
//     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
handlerGroup({ T1: handleT1, T2: handleT2 }) // expected: (key: string) => number | string
```

The problem is due to how I typed `handleGroup`, which I'm not entirely sure how to approach it.

So my question is, how can I let `handleGroup` infer all of the possible `O` based on the record?

## [See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgOwCYBsICcA8BJANFAeQD4oBeKAbygEsAuKPKAe3oPwAtFUN6AKOhgEoyJAlAC+AbgBQ0gGYBXBAGNg1JgiidkadAHF0TBWBz5ivbd3QBnegCUIypuiSZrwdNQQBzfPB0YpoRERIJ8ANYQIPTunj7CpKKU0lBQ6BDACuiavJHRULFe3gkkFCmpUE4I7pQ0HFy6EmRaDRjWANp5ALoyFWkZWZqWuvyCvRLS4rJVNcMQACoAjPT+VpgICgC2AEYY+Bs7GCTkVAKL+CxQ5y0B6HzUJTQTM8A33PMATCutWAe76PhCj5jrUzhd6AAiRYQ+q3e6PagAOmATAAyh4irxhFNpHN9IZjLwqEt6HMlhJhAB6SkRKIxDHxERQP4YXE-AxGMBEqCfUmtT4UqDU2n5IHFJli2TUnngaAAclWunWW3+gIZ3iIcpo1mZTFecGs1mo3gQcG2aCgKMtsqgCp+ysOAOZKqOcsR0mlqXmsp1TDkUDAhkg6FAtqYWrg6RoKiYmzAcDU5og7s9FW9kFtYq11B1CD1UANRpNZotVtAGblLPQbt4HwAzB8PoI2bcOYTics3mglvheV2Fh9BdKIAAPSCqCBIEX0uLixLOx1QAA+BXV0iAA)

Comment: `handlerGroup<string, string | number>({ T1: handleT1, T2: handleT2 })` doesn't fit your needs ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler no, since I want the type to be inferred instead

Answer (score 1):

I [solved](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgOwCYBsICcA8BJANFAeQD4oBeKAbygEsAuKPKAe3oPwAtFUN6AKOhgEoyJAlAC+AbgBQ00JCgBBTABUS5FVAgAPYBGQBnKACUIAYybokmA8HTUEAc3zxkaLIhD4HAMwxQAVSISAH5AqHoECAA3DBlpHwBXBDNgaiYEKE43DABxdCZEsEwYLV19JCNTCysbOwdnWC53TE98T2CiXmzudAN6GEE+AGsIEHpbeydhUhJleQgmHyzmjAMSCmkoKHQIYET0TN5R8ahJhpmNre2oCwRbShoOVfQJMhWcvoBtE4BdGRuOz2B0yPXc-EEAIk0nEsjuDzBEBUAEYBi9MAhEgBbABGGHwmNxGHUjwEyPwLCg5I+vT41EuNGh8OANLQKgATGjPhjsXj0Phzk4SVQyRT6AAiZHi56fOkM6gAOmATAAyvUnLxhLDpIj0PlCmBeFQUfRESiJMIAPSWkZjCbqxwMwl8nUvfVFI1QDmm1Yci1Qa2206Cx0iM4O12fd2G42o1lI6ne+N+8RWm1QY528NTUOzbMNKAAHygzow0iAA) it by moving the handler itself as a generic, and then infer its O:

```js
type Handler<I, O> = { i: I, o: O, handler: (i: I) => O };

type A<T> = T extends Record<string, Handler<any, infer U>> ? U : never;

function handlerGroup<H extends Record<string, Handler<any, any>>>(handlers: H): (key: string) => A<typeof handlers> {
  return (key: string) => {
    const { i, handler } = handlers[key];
    return handler(i);
  }
}
```